# Typescript Map of Arbitrary Generics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics

I'm trying to define two types, which should look something like:

```
export type IQuery<P, U>  = {
  request: string;
  params: (props: P, upsteam?: U) => object;
  key: (props: P, upstream?: U) => string;
  forceRequest: boolean;
  depends?: QueryMap
}

export type QueryMap = {
  [k: string]: IQuery
};
```

The constraints I'm trying to express are that `params` and `key` have the same types for their two arguments, and that a QueryMap is just a mapping from a string to an arbitrary `IQuery` (doesn't matter what the types are). The compiler complains here because it wants a type to be specified for `IQuery`, but the point is that each `IQuery` in the map should be independently parameterized. Is there any way to express this in typescript?

Additionally, if possible, I'd like to get information/guarantees about the shape of the upstream `QueryMap`s present in the `IQuery` as I iterated through this tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *simplest* thing you can do is this:

```
export type QueryMap = {
  [k: string]: IQuery<any, any>
};
```

It's not completely type-safe, but it is not too far off what you're trying to represent.  If you don't want to lose type information for a value of type `QueryMap`, allow the compiler to infer a narrower type and use a generic helper function to ensure it is a valid `QueryMap`, like this:

```
const asQueryMap = <T extends QueryMap>(t: T) => t;

const queryMap = asQueryMap({
  foo: {
    request: "a",
    params(p: string, u?: number) { return {} },
    key(p: string, u?: number) { return "hey" },
    forceRequest: true
  }
});
```

The value `queryMap.foo.params` is still known to be a method that accepts a `string` and an optional `number`, even though the type `QueryMap['foo']['params']` isn't.

If you specify something not assignable to a `QueryMap` you will get an error:

```
const bad = asQueryMap({
  foo: {
    request: "a",
    params(p: string, u?: number) { return {} },
    key(p: string, u?: number) { return "hey" },
    forceRequest: true
  },
  bar: {
    request: 123,
    params(p: number, u?: string) {return {}},
    key(p: number, u?: string) {return "nope"},
    forceRequest: false
  }
}); // error! bar.request is a number
```

---

The not-completely type-safe problem is shown here:

```
const notExactlySafe = asQueryMap({
  baz: {
    request: "a",
    params(p: number, u?: string) { return {} },
    key(p: string, u?: number) { return "hey" },
    forceRequest: true
  }
});
```

This is accepted, even though there's no consistent reasonable values of `P` and `U` that works here (which is what happens when you use `any`).  If you need to lock this down more, you can try to have TypeScript infer sets of `P` and `U` values from the value or warn you if it cannot, but it's not staightforward.

For completeness, here's how I'd do it... use [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to infer `P` and `U` for each element of your `QueryMap` by inspecting the `params` method, and then verify that the `key` method matches it.

```
const asSaferQueryMap = <T extends QueryMap>(
  t: T & { [K in keyof T]:
    T[K]['params'] extends (p: infer P, u?: infer U) => any ? (
      T[K] extends IQuery<P, U> ? T[K] : IQuery<P, U>
    ) : never
  }
): T => t;
```

Now the following will still work:

```
const queryMap = asSaferQueryMap({
  foo: {
    request: "a",
    params(p: string, u?: number) { return {} },
    key(p: string, u?: number) { return "hey" },
    forceRequest: true
  }
});
```

while this will now be an error:

```
const notExactlySafe = asSaferQueryMap({
  baz: {
    request: "a",
    params(p: number, u?: string) { return {} },
    key(p: string, u?: number) { return "hey" },
    forceRequest: true
  }
}); // error, string is not assignable to number
```

This increases your type safety marginally at the expense of a fairly complicated bit of type juggling in the type of `asSaferQueryMap()`, so I don't know that it's worth it.  `IQuery<any, any>` is probably good enough for most purposes.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: That helps quite a bit. The thing about conditional types and using the infer keyword is more or less what I was looking for. I should say that these maps are going to be predefined (They are the queries used throughout the app), so I am okay with making them types themselves; I just wanted the linter/compiler to yell when I make a malformed query. I also want to make some guarantees about the shape of certain function returns, i.e. `getResponse(QueryMap)` would have a return shape equal to all the keys in the map and upstream maps. This is great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IQuery<any, any>`.

I'm not sure what you're hoping for in the second part of the question.  TypeScript doesn't give you runtime type information.  If you just want to have type variables to refer to as you manipulate a single `IQuery`, you can pass an `IQuery<any, any>` to a `function myFunction<P, U>(iquery: IQuery<P, U>) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

## The Solution

I removed from your types unrelevant information just for clarity. The solution boils-down to basically add 3 lines of code.

```js
type Check<T> = QueryMap<T extends QueryMap<infer U> ? U : never>

export type IQuery<P, U, TQueryMap extends Check<TQueryMap>> = {
    prop1: (param1: P, param2?: U) => number;
    prop2: (param1: P, param2?: U) => string;
    prop3?: TQueryMap
}

export type QueryMap<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
};

// type constructors
const asQueryMap = <T>(x: QueryMap<T>) => x
const asQuery = <P, U, V extends QueryMap<any>>(x: IQuery<P, U, V>) => x
```

## Considerations

All types are correctly infered by the compiler.

*Important*: If (and only if) you use the `type constructors` (see above) to construct yours structures you can consider yourself totally statically type-safe.

Bellow are the test cases:

### Test of `no compile errors`

```
// Ok -- No compile-time error and correctly infered !

const queryMap = asQueryMap({
    a: asQuery({
        prop1: (param1: string, param2?: number) => 10,
        prop2: (param1: string, param2?: number) => "hello",
    }),

    b: asQuery({
        prop1: (param1: string, param2?: string) => 10,
        prop2: (param1: string, param2?: string) => "hello",
    }),

    c: asQuery({
        prop1: (param1: Array<number>, param2?: number) => 10,
        prop2: (param1: Array<number>, param2?: number) => "hello",
    })
})


const query = asQuery({
    prop1: (param1: string, param2?: number) => 10,
    prop2: (param1: string, param2?: number) => "hello",
    prop3: queryMap    
})
```

### Test of `Compile-time errors`

You can see bellow some compile-time errors beeing catched.

```
// Ok --> Compile Error: 'prop2' signature is wrong

const queryMap2 = asQueryMap({
    a: asQuery({
        prop1: (param1: Array<string>, param2?: number) => 10,
        prop2: (param1: Array<number>, param2?: number) => "hello",
    })
})


// Ok --> Compile Error: 'prop3' is not of type QueryMap<any>

const query2 = asQuery({
    prop1: (param1: string, param2?: number) => 10,
    prop2: (param1: string, param2?: number) => "hello",
    prop3: 10 // <---- Error !
})
```

Thank you
Cheers