# Typescript Map of generics

Tags: typescript, generics

Im trying to get each `Field` in `ObjectType` to have its own generic, so the `resolve` fn of each Field has to return the type defined in the `type` property.

```
type Scalars = {
  ID: string;
  Int: number;
  Float: number;
  String: string;
  Boolean: boolean;
};

type Field<T extends keyof Scalars> = {
  type: T,
  resolve: () => Scalars[T];
}

type ObjectType<T extends keyof Scalars> = {
  [key: string]: Field<T>
}

const objectType = <T extends keyof Scalars>(config: ObjectType<T>): any => 'todo';

objectType({
  id: {
    type: 'Int',
    // type of `resolve` is `() => (string | number)`, should be `() => number`
    resolve: () => '123',
  },
  name: {
    type: 'String',
    // should be `() => string`
    resolve: () => 123,
  },
});
```

After investigating some other SO questions I found a solution that almost solves my problem in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51547767/11042710

Here's the TS playground where I attempt what was suggested above
[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgQwDYIE4GcoF4oG8BQUUAkgCIBcU6wqAlgHYDmA3ISfcJfQK4C2ARhFSsiAMSQB7BJyg8BQkbBoNGlanSaKAQhIlIICepX679h1gF9W+UJCijaEJABMAPABUoEAB7AI9Z0wAawgQCQAzWEQUDAA+bDw2WwhKdwAaNlQIdD0ANxSoAAoASmx4+GQ0dABtdwBdS3wbcGgAeX4AKwg4YHcWhIIiapCQNWUmOsoHJzdDEFj8Cya4CXpqKAlO7t7+nFc2Tx8-AMx2rp6+yHxYwpX6cNpVKE8AMjwoaoBpKAYoEYjnpNnl86l5fP5Au9kpQGOEhFAAApQCxQAD8wM+oKOEMw0xcrgR8XR7hBUCmjnxhLJsgg+VQyOKlDmZSgAHJgBJnBJWdZNucdpBCoMfs5KMKiNC2TBxoxWRkiEQAPSKqDJDaRAAGWRySHyGp+mA1JRZhXUKigAB9ZHxBKhihq0lQABYSbguKCCKBG0pYeJmpgathEbV5ArG31QACMACYAMzy5EJ2jOAri1UtSis4gcOVBqDK52u92e70suS2wMKqAh3Vhn3xVkx2O5ogWDIWYqsIA).

But it fails when I try to pass the `infer P` type to a generic that `extends keyof Scalars`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `Field<..>` types can form a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) like this:

```
type Fields = { [K in keyof Scalars]: Field<K> }[keyof Scalars];
```

Here the type `Fields` is equivalent to

```
type Fields = Field<"ID"> | Field<"Int"> | Field<"Float"> | 
  Field<"String"> | Field<"Boolean">
```

where all terms in the union have a common `type` filed of a string literal type that can be used to discriminate between them.  That's good, because it means that your `objectType()` method can involve a lot less generic hoop-jumping, since the `config` property values can be constrained to the specific type `Fields`:

```
const objectType = <T extends Record<keyof T, Fields>>(config: T): any => 'todo';
```

Now all we're doing is constraining `config` to be an object with any keys (`Record<keyof T, ...>`) and whose values are all `Fields`.  Let's see if it works.  This is is the intended use:

```
objectType({
  id: {
    type: 'String',
    resolve: () => "123",
  },
  ide: {
    type: 'Int',
    resolve: () => 123,
  },
});
```

and this is what happens when you do it wrong:

```
objectType({
  id: { // error! number is not assignable to string
    type: 'String',
    resolve: () => 123,
  },
  ide: { // error! string is not assignable to boolean
    type: 'Boolean',
    resolve: () => "123",
  },
});
```

Those are the errors you expect, right?

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: That does work! But I probably should have given the full context because the types were a bit more complex. 

The `type` property cant only take a scalar, it also can take another ObjectType, and in the case it takes an ObjectType the resolve function should return a generic I pass to the ObjectType. Heres a shortened link to the playground bit.ly/3dDlNsJ (SO complains about shortened links and TS playground link is too long for a comment)

Comment: I am not particularly inclined to wade through that code with the `Field` definition being a cumbersome set of nested conditional types.  If you make it more minimal I'll take a look.

Comment: fair, I thought I'd give the full context this time but that wasnt necessary, heres the new playground link bit.ly/2T6hWuH

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Qmba2N) work for your use case?  (Haven't seen your new link yet)

Comment: it doesn't because the value returned by `resolve` when `type` is an ObjectType is not the type of its fields, but instead a generic that will be passed to ObjectType. 

Maybe it could default to the type of the fields when no generic is passed, and thats how some libs do it, but its very important that the consumer is able to pass in an arbitrary type to ObjectType that will both be used as the first argument of the ObjectType field's resolve fn AND as the returned type of a fields `resolve` fn when this ObjectType is used as `type`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/Gm3ELw) then?  I think if that doesn't help I'm going to have to bail entirely.  If it *does* help, I guess you can update the question or else open a new one so that the example code motivates the solution.  In any case, there's only so much you can expect the compiler to be able to infer when it comes to some of these deeply nested types.  So you might need to resort to manual annotations or assertions more than you'd like

Comment: Yea, it doesn't solve it because now the generic passed to objectType dictates its fields, but the generic should only be the type of the first arg of `resolve` and of the return type of the `resolve` fn of a field using this type. I thought it might've been impossible cause theres only two libs that solve this problem, one of them use code generation and the other has a funky decorator api. I'll leave the question open in case anyone wants to chime in, thanks a lot!